# GXT3 VerticalLayoutContainer height bug

Tags: gwt, gxt

I little speak english :( (i use gtranslate...)

I create GWT2.5(with requestfactory)+GXT3 MVP application

My Main View is a BorderLayout

west: shortcut panel(verticalLayoutContainer)

south: toolbar (status)

north: toolbar (menu)

my codes:

DesktopView.ui.xml (Main view):
http://pastebin.com/xbeUzDwi

DesktopView.java
http://pastebin.com/WguE6CVf

DesktopActivity.java
http://pastebin.com/adejJwu0

about grid view:
http://pastebin.com/nFPrGpd1
my MVP auto call createGrid()

error image(pagingToolbar) [image]

if i replace in gridView 
verticalLayoutContainer.add(grid, new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1)); => verticalLayoutContainer.add(grid, new VerticalLayoutData(1, 1));
error image(do not show grid) [image]

what is the problem my code ? ???

but if i add code to DesktopActivity:

public void onEvent(....){
.
.

```
                            DesktopActivity.getContentPanel().setWidget(event.getWidget());
                                                    if (event.getWidget() instanceof VerticalLayoutContainer) {
                                                        ((VerticalLayoutContainer) event.getWidget()).onResize();
                                                    }
```

direct call onResize, then there is no problem if you add...

this GXT3 bug or I make a mistake on something

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: My entrypoint:  http://pastebin.com/w1jHBwMY

Answer (score 0):

The BorderLayoutContainer does not automatically find the size of the edge components. You will have to define the sizes of these areas manually.

```
<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData"
         field="northData">
    <ui:attributes size="30" />
</ui:with>
```

This section says that the north section of the container should be 30 pixels high. The same can be done for all edges.